# Refresh a DIV content after faded it out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got X DIV (TopRowRight1, TopRowRight2, TopRowRight3...) , each containing a different Google Geochart generated by a php page : GeochartPerProvince.php?template=X.

```
        function getResult(template){
            jQuery.post("GeochartPerProvince.php?template="+template,function( data ) {
                jQuery("#TopRowRight"+template).html(data);
            });
        }

        jQuery().ready(function(){
            getResult(1);
            setInterval("getResult(1)",10000);
            getResult(2);
            setInterval("getResult(2)",10000);
            getResult(3);
            setInterval("getResult(3)",10000);
        });

        jQuery(function () {

            var $els = $('div[id^=TopRowRight]'),
                i = 0,
                len = $els.length;
                $els.slice(1).hide();

            setInterval(function () {

                $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {

                    i = (i + 1) % len
                    $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
                })
            }, 5000)
        });
```

Every 5 seconds, i fade out one and fade in the next one. This works perfectly.
For now, the php page in the DIV is refreshed every 10 seconds. This works too.

But what i dream about is that the php page in the DIV is reloaded AFTER the DIV is faded out instead of every 10 seconds. How to do it?

---

Solved. How it works properly:

```
    function getResult(template){
        jQuery.post("GeochartPerProvince.php?template="+template,function( data ) {
            jQuery("#TopRowRight"+template).html(data);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getResult(0);
        getResult(1);
        getResult(2);
        //setInterval("getResult(2)",10000); <== keep this piece of code in case of need.
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $els = $('div[id^=TopRowRight]'),
            i = 0,
            len = $els.length;
            $els.slice(1).hide();

        setInterval(function () {

            $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {

                i = (i + 1) % len
                getResult(i);
                $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
            })
        }, 10000)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a callback function after the element has been faded out. So why not call your `getResult` function inside it?

```
$el.fadeOut(function(){
  // stuff
  getResult(i)
})
```

Comment: Hi, that's the first thing i tryed. But it did not work... After reading your comment, I finaly started DIV numbers with 0 (instead of 1), then it work perfectly. Don't ask me why ! Thank you anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions and an example code for you to achieve what you need :

- Use $ instead of jQuery for easier reading / writing
- `$(document).ready` is the proper start point for dom related functions
- If only one div is visible at a time, do not use too many divs. Most of the time one div is enough for alternating / refreshing content. If there is in/out animation or cross-fading, two divs would be needed. (Example below uses two divs)
- Avoid using setInterval except you really really need. Logics with setTimeout better handles unexpected delays such $.post may cause.

start with html code something like this:

```
...
<div class="top-row-right" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="top-row-right" style="display:none"></div>
...
```

js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var len = 4; // 'I got X DIV..' This is where we put the value of X.
    var template = -1;

    function refreshChart() {

        template = (template + 1) % len;

        $.post("GeochartPerProvince.php?template="+template, function(data) {
            var offscreenDiv = ('.top-row-right:hidden');
            var onscreenDiv = ('.top-row-right:visible');

            offScreenDiv.html(data);
            onScreenDiv.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                offScreenDiv.fadeIn();
                setTimeout(refreshChart, 10000);
            });

        });
    }
    refreshChart();

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll have a look at your way. But as i generate things also related to the DIV id in the PHP page, it's easier (even if dirty) for me to create as many DIV as different Geochart templates i have. Already replaced the JQuery() things by $(document) as you suggest.